Порядок слов в языке: почему сначала идет подлежащее, а потом сказуемое?
Почему язык устроен так, что сначала идет подлежащее, а затем сказуемое?  Почему мозг ставит себя на первое место, а не глагол? С чем это связано?

«Почему сначала идет подлежащее?..» ===  В Вашем предложении сначала идёт сказуемое, а не подлежащее. Впрочем, как и в моём предыдущем…

А вот тогда, почему мы говорим «я иду туда», а не «иду я туда»?

Ответ на комментарий
Мне тоже нравится сравнивать русскую и английскую грамматику – при сравнении лучше понимаешь грамматический строй своего языка.
В русском языке с помощью склонения существительных и спряжения глаголов можно четко обозначить грамматическую связь, в том числе согласование и управление, но этого нет или недостаточно развито в английском языке.  Соответственно, мы можем позволить себе более свободный порядок слов.
Это сложилось исторически. Скорее всего, оба языка унаследовали грамматику (русский  из греческого языка, а английский из романской группы), а в дальнейшем развивались самостоятельно. Мы оставили  сложную систему словоизменения (склонения и спряжения), но упростили времена,  а в английском все наоборот.  Ну это я так думаю, может,  кто поправит))
Сравним:
(1) Сейчас дни холодные,   даже дети не гуляют.  The days are cold now, even the children don't walk.
ХолОдные сейчас дни,  даже дети не гуляют. The days are cold now, even the children don't walk.
Английское предложение не изменилось, а в русском варианте инверсия подлежащего  и сказуемого. Для чего?  Мы логически подчеркиваем сказуемое в инверсированной позиции, а у них такой возможности скорее нет.
(2)  ХолОдная погода  была этим  летом,  а холодную погоду мы не любИм.
The weather was cold this summer, and we don't like cold weather.
В русском языке  подлежащее (И.п.) и  прямое дополнение (В.п.)  стоят в начале предложения, а в английском языке  дополнение  нужно ставить после сказуемого-глагола. У нас тоже такой же прямой порядок  (глагол + прямое дополнение), но мы можем позволить себе инверсию для логического выделения слов.
В русском языке  важна интонация,  а носители английского языка этого просто не понимают.  Их удивляет повышение голоса на ударном слоге в начале или в середине  предложения (мы как бы «кричим» не по делу).


При достаточном свободном порядке слов в русском языке все же выделяется прямой и обратный порядок слов.

Наступила весна. Сказуемое + подлежащее, обратный порядок слов.
Снег растаял. Подлежащее + сказуемое, прямой порядок слов.

Порядок слов в простом предложении определяется его актуальным членением по схеме тема — рема, о чем говорится — что говорится.

Листья уже пожелтели. Тема — листья.
Уже пожелтели листья. Тема — изменения в природе.
На первом месте всегда тема, а порядок слов для подлежащего и сказуемого может быть как прямым,так  и обратным.

Рассмотрим предложение: Птицы улетают // осенью.

Здесь тема  — птицы улетают (грамматическая основа), и порядок слов действительно прямой. Поэтому вопрос в какой-то мере правомерен.
Как это можно объяснить? Подлежащее обозначает предмет, а сказуемое — его предикативный признак, то есть действие.
Сравнить для именного сказуемого: День теплый. Здесь сказуемое обозначает признак предмета (его состояние) в текущий момент.
Другими словами, при прямом порядке слов на первом месте предмет, а на втором его предикативный признак.

Итак, сказуемое — это предикативный признак предмета. Может  быть, этот член предложения менее важен? А вот это нет! Сказуемое даже более значимо, чем подлежащее. У подлежащего номинативное (назывное) значение, но такое же значение есть у слова и у словосочетания.

Предложение имеет место только тогда, когда обозначен предикативный признак предмета (время и модальность/наклонение глагола). Грамматическое подлежащее есть в двусоставных предложениях, но его нет в большинстве односоставных, например: Ветрено, похолодало. Стоит ли идти на прогулку? Не знаю...

Хорошо, тогда почему в Английском языке сначала идет подлежащее, а затем глагол? Почему в Английской нельзя менять порядок слов, а у нас можно. Если так сложилось с давних времен, то почему так сложилось с давних времен?
